# Postpositive "unknown"

Tags: adjectives, past-participles, postpositive

*The house was broken into by a person or persons **unknown**.*

[image]
[image]
Whis is (the adjective?) *unknown* used after the noun phrase here?

Comment: It's an idiom. Read it aloud and you can see how it feels more dramatic than "an unknown person or persons".

Comment: It's the sort of phrase that lends itself to official records. Gives no information, but it's subject to change when more information is available.

Comment: It's Law & Order speak.

Comment: See the treatment of postnominal adjective positioning at [Why 'inspector general' and not 'general inspector'? ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240591/why-inspector-general-and-not-general-inspector-like-german-generalinspek/240593#240593).

Answer (score 1):

There are some single adjectives that can occur postpositively. Your example is like those in [12i], below, in that the postpositive construction alternates with the attributive one with the same meaning. It is not possible to predict, on some general grounds, which adjectives can be used this way; some can, others can't, and the best we can do is record, for each adjective, to which category it belongs.

In addition, as was mentioned in the comments, *a person or persons unknown* is a cliche that is close to becoming a [set phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_phrase) in some contexts.

Here is the relevant discussion from [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468)  Ch. 5,  §14.2 (pp. 445-446):

> **(b) Adjectives and AdjPs**
>
> The basic rule for the placement of adjectives and AdjPs is that single adjectives and phrases without their own post-head dependents occur in attributive position, while others occur **postpositively,** i.e. after the head of the NP, as in *members [**dissatisfied** with the board's decision].* Special rules apply with compound determinatives like *somebody, anything,* etc.: see §9.6. For the rest, there are certain specific adjectives that can or must occur postpositively. Representative examples are given in [12] (see also Ch. 6, §4.2):
>
> [12]  i  *the only day **suitable,** years **past,** proof **positive,** matters **financial,**
>
>              all things **Irish***
>         ii  *the people **present,** the cars **involved,** the students **concerned,** the city **proper*** 
>        iii  *the heir **apparent,** the body **politic,** the president **elect,** the devil **incarnate,**
>
>              the poet **laureate,** a notary **public*** 
>        iv  *the house [currently **ablaze**], all people [now **alive**], the ones **asleep***
>
> The examples in [i2i] alternate with the attributive construction: compare *the only suitable day,* etc. The postpositive use of these adjectives is subject to severe restrictions. Adjectives in *-able* or *-ible,* like *suitable* and *possible,* require an attributive superlative or *only,* compare *the best result possible* and **the result possible.* Postpositive **past** occurs with temporal nouns (cf. **approaches past*), and *positive* only with *proof.* The last two examples have general nouns as head and denote domains; the adjectives *financial* and *Irish* are like restrictors (§9.6) in that they must immediately follow the head.
>
> The adjectives in [12ii] occur both attributively and postpositively, but with a difference in sense. Postpositive *present* (or *absent*) denotes a temporary state of affairs: compare *the present government.* The same applies to *involved* and *concerned,* though here the attributive sense differs more (cf. *deeply involved activists, concerned parents*). Postpositive *proper* means "in the strict/proper sense of the term". With *net* and *gross* the choice of position depends not on the meaning but on the head: they follow specific sums (*fifty dollars net*) but otherwise precede (*my net income*).
>
> The examples in [12iii] are fixed phrases, with no attributive alternant. The adjectives in [iv] are ones which are altogether excluded from attributive position.