# Which Is the correct: public notary or notary public?

Tags: word-order

My dad's asking me if he should say "I'm a public notary practicing in Australia" or "I'm a notary public practicing in Australia".

I thought notary public was nonsense, but when I googled it, it seems both are used. Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: *Notary public* is common usage in Canada and the United States.

Comment: In India also, it is Notary public.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27706/is-it-common-to-use-the-borrowed-noun-adjective-form-for-borrowed-french-phrases

Answer (score 2):

I am a Colorado notary public, notary training instructor, and notary historian.

**Postpositive adjectives** are adjectives that follow the nouns they modify.
In Latin, the phrase is **notarius publicus**.
The English phrase “notary public” shows its origin from the Latin language. Notaries trace their history to Tiro, a servant scribe of famous Roman Senator Cicero.

For many centuries, notaries were members of the clergy, who knew Latin.

Some other English phrases that use postpositive adjectives are:

- accounts payable
- attorney general
- postmaster general
- court martial
- God almighty
- poet laureate
- words unspoken

See my original blog post: [Notary Public or Public Notary?](https://abclegaldocs.com/blog-Colorado-Notary/notary-public-public-notary/)